# How to get rid of the brackets appearing in non-commutative multiply?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I am getting output as

```
(-T1**T2**T3)**T4**T5
```

How to get rid of the brackets that are appearing in the output?

I want my output as

```
-T1**T2**T3**T4**T5
```

Comment: 1. Please put any code you post in code blocks. Formatting help is automatically displayed for all new users when they edit a post. 2. It is not clear what you are asking.  Give a *complete* example, include your input, explain what you want to achieve in plain terms.  Ask a friend to read your question before submitting it. Make sure he understands it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Non-commutative multiplication](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) is by definition [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) but not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). The minus sign in your formula, which is a [regular multiplication](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html) with the number $-1$, blocks the automatic application of the associative property. You can see this by using [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html):

```
(-T1 ** T2 ** T3) ** T4 ** T5 // FullForm
```

> NonCommutativeMultiply[Times[-1, NonCommutativeMultiply[T1, T2, T3]], T4, T5]

To circumvent this problem you have to state the allowed transformation rules yourself, for example the associativity with regular multiplication by a number:

```
(-T1 ** T2 ** T3) ** T4 ** T5 /. (u_?NumericQ a_) ** b_ -> u (a ** b)
```

> -T1 ** T2 ** T3 ** T4 ** T5